# Could total 2020 flu deaths be low due to Covid19 countermeasures?

Tags: virology, epidemiology, coronavirus

A working assumption is that Covid19 countermeasures will also reduce seasonal flu transmission and mortality.

Could this effect be so large that the 2020 total global deaths from both causes will be lower than the annual expected deaths from seasonal flu alone ?

I understand global seasonal flu mortality is around 40k/month

Comment: This seems too speculative to me - do you possibly have a citation for this "working assumption"?

Comment: Contact minimisation will reduce all pathogen transmission. Are there references to the contrary ? https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsif.2009.0302.focus

Comment: In the regions where they heavily restricted public events, closed schools, etc. because of COVID-19, it's very likely there will be lower flu incidence and mortality. The problem is how to prove that, because the incidence of flu differed grossly from year to year in past years when there were no countermeasures.

Comment: This is a question and answer site for problems about biological processes. Such problems should be capable of being answered objectively. Questions about the expected effect of a current epidemic of one disease on the future mortality caused by another disease are not about biological problems in terms of this site and are only capable of speculative opinions. Your question is therefore off-topic. Some reputable sources concerning the current coronavirus pandemic can be found [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036).

Comment: @cumfy if they don't go down after all this fuss it will be embarrassing. I have to go to the bathroom when my nose itches just so I can wash before scratching it. Gonna be annoyed if that doesn't save anyone, covid 19 or not.

Comment: @David I'm sorry this epidemiological question isn't to your taste. Viral transmission mechanisms, their efficiency and analysis of their variation and sequelae between similar viruses is a central topic in epidemiology. Many statistical inferences can be drawn from carefully recorded epidemic data.

Comment: @cumfy — Please read what I have written — it is not a matter of taste. I explained that your question only admitted of speculative answers and was therefore off-topic according the standards of this site. You post here without even finishing reading the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) (you lack the corresponding badge), never mind the [Help on asking questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) where this is laid out. New contributors are welcome to SE Biology, but they are expected to read and follow the "rules".